# How to check if an element is clickable using Protractor test

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

I have an element that does not allow it to be clickable using CSS property `pointer-events: none;` How can I check whether that element is clickable or not as doing a `.click()` on the element throws an exception that I cannot catch `UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point` The element is a link so I just want to check if the redirect happened but because of this error it ends the test right away and try catch cannot catch the exception.

Comment: Please try this:    browser.driver.findElement(by.css('CSS_PATH')).then(function(element)
  {
   try 
   {
    
    element.click();
   }
   catch(err) {
    console.log('In catch block');
   }
       }, function(err) {
   console.info('Element is not clickable');
  });

Comment: That does not work. Also the console.info('Element is not clickable') is not possible to reach as the element exist of page and that callback only gets called if it is missing from the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about protractor, but using plain JS you can do:

```
window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('pointer-events') == 'none';
```

however support for [*getComputedStyle*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-ViewCSS) may not be available in all browsers you wish to support, see [MDN compatibility matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle), which indicates no support in IE 8, however it may not support the *pointer-events* CSS property anyway.

Comment: So I solved it by running the script you send using `expect(browser.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('pointer-events')").toBe('none')`

Answer (score 2):

if you really want to use protractor you can use the following:

expect(            protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).not.toBe(true);

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two methods to check it.

1) Using `ExpectedConditions`

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be clickable.
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable($('#abc')), 5000);
```

If not found or not clickable, will return error.

2) Using protractor's `isEnabled`, `isDisplayed` and `isPresent`

So as far as my understanding goes, you can create `isClickable`, which will return true if element is present, displayed and enabled and false otherwise:

```
function isClickable(element) {
    return element.isPresent().then((isPresent) => {
        if (isPresent) {
            return element.isDisplayed().then((isDisplayed) => {
                if (isDisplayed) {
                    return element.isEnabled();
                }
                return false;
            });
         }
         return false;
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote small check utility method, keep in mind it will click on element immediately when it become clickable:

```
import { ElementFinder, promise } from 'protractor';

export let testHelpers = {
  isClickable(el: ElementFinder): promise.Promise<boolean> {
    return new promise.Promise(resolve => {
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        el.click().then(() => {
          clearInterval(interval);
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(true);
          }, 500);
        }, () => { });
      }, 100);
    });
  }
}
```

In your test code:
    mport { testHelpers } from '../src/core/e2e/helpers';

```
describe('App', () => {
  it('should do something', () {
    let btn = $('.cls');
    browser.wait(testHelpers.isClickable(btn), 3000);
  });
});
```